# Layout inflater is not inflating view

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

I feel that in this code my layout is not being attached.I verified by toast,log.d but nothing worked.Here this I am using for a recycler view view holder.Code is below

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.posts_layout,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}
```

and onBindViewHolder.I user log to check if this method is being used but,its not used

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    Log.d("binded", true.toString())
    val post = mPost[position]
    getPublisherInfo(holder.profileImage ,holder.userName , holder.userFullName ,post.getpublisher())
    Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getpostId()).placeholder(R.drawable.image).into(holder.postImage)
}
```

I also checked if my list size id 0 for it to not come.For it use used log and it showed the list size 5 which is correct.This meant that my data is being retrieved from database.So it think that the my layout inflater is not working.The code for it is.

```
private fun readPosts() {
    val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
    postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            postList.clear()
            for(snapshot in snapshot.children){
                val post = snapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
                for (uid in (followingList as ArrayList<String>)) {
                    if (post!!.getpublisher().equals(uid)) {
                        postList.add(post)
                    }
                    Log.d("added", postList.size.toString())
                    Log.d("added", postList.toString())
                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}

    })
}
```

My entire adapter code is

```
package com.u_me_pro.free.Adapters

class PostAdapter(private val mContext: Context,private val mPost: List<Post>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private lateinit var firebaseUser : FirebaseUser


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.posts_layout,parent,false)
    Log.d("attached layout","true")
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

 class ViewHolder(@NonNull itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
    var userName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_post)
    var userFullName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_full_name_post)
    var commentCount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_count)
    var likeCount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.love_count)
    var profileImage: RoundedImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image_post)
    var postImage: RoundedImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image)
    var like: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_like)
    var comment: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_comment)
    var save: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_save)
}



override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    Log.d("binded", true.toString())
    val post = mPost[position]
    getPublisherInfo(holder.profileImage ,holder.userName , holder.userFullName ,post.getpublisher())
    Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getpostId()).placeholder(R.drawable.image).into(holder.postImage)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mPost.size
}

private fun getPublisherInfo(profileImage: RoundedImageView, userName: TextView, userFullName: TextView, publisherId: String) {
    val usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(publisherId)
    Log.d("publisher id",publisherId)
    usersRef.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                val user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                userName.text = user!!.getFullname()
                userFullName.text = user.getFullname()
                Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImage)
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
        }
    })
}
}
```

Please help me out soon.
Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I've noticed reading your code is that you're adding the posts in postList variable, but you're reading the single post from using mPost[position], so from a different variable. Are you somehow assigning the value of postList to mPost? If not, that could be the reason why it is not working how you expect

Comment: I guess I am not

https://i.stack.imgur.com/as95v.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFpuG.png
But I am using them in two different files!!One in adapter and other in my fragment

Comment: Ok, just try to change mPost[position] to postList[position]. This should do it

Comment: But that variable exists in my fragment.Not in my adapter

Comment: Bt wait.My layout inflater is not working.Other wise in my log I would have seen it!! That my onBindViewHolder is being executed!

Comment: I can say this becoz I put log to check if it gets executed.


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    Log.d("binded", true.toString()) 
}



But I am not getting in my run section not my log

Comment: and as I said that all my posts and size are being retrieved but they are not being displayed in the recycler view

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I tried but there will be no use as this method itself is not being called.And there is no error too.

Comment: Can you please add your adapter's full code?

Comment: I have edited my question with the adapters code.

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the post list and notifying the adapter of a change but it doesn't appear that you're ever actually passing in the updated list to the adapter.

```
postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Won't do anything if the actual data in your adapter hasn't changed.

You should add a way to update your post list in the adapter such as

```
fun setPostData(posts: List<Post>) {
    this.adapterPosts = posts
    notifyDataSetChanged() // Either call this here or where you were before
}
```

This would also require you to create a new variable to hold the passed-in list

```
private var adapterPosts = mPosts
```

Comment: I am unable to understand it.

Comment: Sorry! Let me know which part you want me to clarify and i'll try my best to edit it to make it more understandable!

Essentially what I'm trying to say is, you're initializing your adapter with an empty list (based on the picture in one of your comments). If you want the adapter to display your list of items, you need some method of updating the list that the adapter is currently holding